How do I inject <dxi-item> into a <dx-accordian> using custom components in angular
I am making a template component and need to be able to inject the dxi-item into a nested dx-accordian. My code is as follow:
mc-component.html:

<div>
  <ng-content selection="header">
  <dx-accordian>
    <ng-content selection="mc-inputs"
  </dx-accordian>
<div>


mc-inputs.html:

<dxi-item>
 <mc-input />
 <mc-input />
<dxi-item>


mc-input.html:

<p>It Works! </p>


Can you create a codepen and share it with us?
